# How to amplify DC Voltage to be used like supply to 2km?

Tags: voltage, current, amplifier, dc, remote

I want to turn on a device away from the voltage source to 2 kilometers. My device operates at 24VDC or 48VDC / 35W.

I need to know how is it possible to amplify the voltage from 24Vdc to 240Vdc or higher. In this manner the current needed is lower and loss due to resistance too.

I don't know how to specify the characteristics of my current cable.

Is there something to help me to reach this goal?

Comment: Are you just sending control signals to the device or are you also powering it from the cable?  And do say something about the cable.  Single strand, twisted pair, coax, what's the resistance per unit length (or the wire gauge.)

Comment: Are these two separate questions?

Comment: If you can't specify your current cable, how do you know it will handle 240 volts? And (assuming you're going to bury it), how do you know it will not degrade while buried. And if you're not going to bury it, which means you don't want to dig a 2 km trench, why do you think it won't get chewed by animals? And please don't tell us you don't know the wire gauge. If you don't, find somebody who can tell you, and then tell us.

Comment: The cable isn't problem, becasuse I can select the better option between resistance/price, the problem is the process or circuit for amplification of DC Voltage.

Comment: I need to supply/Send only feed voltage, but to this distance the resistance decrease the power. Isn't signal control, I need to send voltage for DC Adaptor.
The signal to be sended throught Fiber Optic Cable.

Comment: Have you considered converting (inverting) it to AC instead of pumping it to a higher DC? AC will travel much further on a given wire with lower losses than DC.

Answer (score 1):

You need a boost converter to lift your 24V DC to 240V DC. Because these are not 100% efficient the power in to supply 240V DC at 35 watts is likely to be about 40 watts.

Then you need to convert it back down to (say) 24 volts at the far end and this will probably mean the full input power will be about 45 watts.

With 40 watts at 240VDC "pumped" onto the cable by the booster the current will be 167 mA and now you have to decide on the wire gauge: -

[image]

If you choose AWG 24 - it has 84.2 ohms per 1000m. Double this for the return path and multiply by 2 for 2km length and you get a total resistance of 337 ohms - this needs to provide 167mA to the load and will accordingly lose voltage on the way.

Simple ohm's law tells you that the volts lost are 0.167 x 436 ohms = 56 volts. This would need to be added to the 240V DC you generate from the boost converter so immediately you are looking to generate more like 296 volts rather than 240 volts.

That's not a problem for the load (or the cable) but your input power has risen to about 50 watts.

AWG 16 has a 2km loop resistance of only 53 ohms so you may choose this instead. With 167 mA flowing the volt drop will be about 8.8 volts so maybe this is a better choice.

Hope this helps you get your head around the iterative process of choosing the right cable to suit your power budget.

Comment: I've got no experience with long cables, but I've heard nearby lightening strikes can ruin your day.  It may depend on how things are grounded too.  If he only needs control maybe fiber optics?

Answer (score 0):

35 watts at 48VDC is about 730 milliamperes into the load with 48 volts across it, so to specify the cable you need to know the tolerance allowable on the input voltage to the load.

Running it at a higher voltage will allow you to use smaller diameter cable, so just for the sake of this exercise let's say the spec on the 48 volts is +/- 10% and the device is linear, so with 43.2 volts across it it'll draw 657 milliamperes from the source.

With a 48 volt source servicing the load and only 43.8 volts getting to the load means that the cable between the source and the load must be dropping the 4.8 volt difference and, with 657 milliamperes running through it, represents a resistance of 7.3 ohms over the 4 kilometer (out and back) run.

That's about 1.83 ohms per kilometer so, perusing a copper wire table, we find that #7 AWG, at 1.634 ohms per kilometer will fill the bill, but the down side is that it'll be expensive to do it that way.

[image]

Another less expensive and, perhaps, more sensible way to do it - if AC mains aren't available at the remote location - would be to send mains power over much smaller diameter wire from the local to the remote location and convert it to 24 or 48 volts DC there; the caveat being, of course, that you're running a moderately high voltage over a fairly long route where lots of untoward things could happen.

Like, for example, a baby chewing through the cable.

Comment: A baby chewing through the cable - the ones that survive are more likely to become hardcore EEs.